# How can i use multiple SQL with node.js and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I tried to put multiple select query with node.js and mysql.
but console prints out some log says there is something wrong about sql..

I also made multipleStatements: true;

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 5,
    host : '*.*.*.*',
    user : 'root',
    password : '****',
    database : 'db',
    multipleStatements: true
});
```

I made this code to calculate host address with network address and subnetmask.
and i want to select lines which are matched to host ip address that i calculated.

I made sql array and put SQLs into array ..
and i made it to String formation and parsed as one sql statement( i mean sql: "sql1; sql2; sql3;....")

```js
 pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            var sql ="";
            var new_sql = new Array();
            if(req.body.search_network){
                var search_data = [req.body.search_network, req.body.search_subnet];
                console.log("*****:"+search_data);
              
               
             
                //calculating host addresses
                var NETWORK = req.body.search_network;
                var SUBNET = req.body.search_subnet;
                var host_cnt = Math.pow(2,(32-SUBNET));
                var split_net = NETWORK.split('.');
                var NET_1 = Number(split_net[0]);
                var NET_2 = Number(split_net[1]);
                var NET_3 = Number(split_net[2]);
                var NET_4 = Number(split_net[3]);
                //network address
                console.log(NET_1+"."+NET_2+"."+NET_3+"."+NET_4);
                
                console.log(Math.floor(1/Math.pow(256,3)));
                
                 for (var i=1; i<host_cnt-1; i++){
                    var new_NET_1 = NET_1 + Math.floor(i/Math.pow(256,3));
                    var new_NET_2 = NET_2 + Math.floor(i/Math.pow(256,2));
                    var new_NET_3 = NET_3 + Math.floor(i/256);
                    var new_NET_4 = NET_4 + Math.floor(i%256);
                //host address
                    var IP_HOST = String(new_NET_1)+"."+String(new_NET_2)+"."+String(new_NET_3)+"."+String(new_NET_4);
                 
                    new_sql.push(" SELECT ARP_TBL.DEVICE_IP as device_ip, IP_MGMT_TBL.IP as ip, IP_MGMT_TBL.IP_TYPE as ip_type, IP_MGMT_TBL.PURPOSE as purpose, IP_MGMT_TBL.OWNER_NAME as name, IP_MGMT_TBL.OWNER_DIV as owner_div, IP_MGMT_TBL.REQUEST_TIME as request_time, ARP_TBL.PORT as port " + "FROM IP_MGMT_TBL left join ARP_TBL on IP_MGMT_TBL.IP = ARP_TBL.ip " +"WHERE ARP_TBL.ip="+IP_HOST);
                                  
                 }               
                
                
                sql = new_sql.join(';')+";";
                console.log(sql);
                
              
              
              // put query to DB and get results within 'rows'
                connection.query(sql, function(err, rows){
                  if(err) console.error("err:" +err);
                  console.log("rows:"+ JSON.stringify(rows));
                   res.render('ipmgmt/detail', {rows: rows});
                   connection.release();
                  });
              


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
; SELECT ARP_TBL.DEVICE_IP as device_ip, IP_MGMT_TBL.IP as ip, IP_MGMT_TBL.IP_TYPE as ip_type, IP_MGMT_TBL.PURPOSE as purpose, IP_MGMT_TBL.OWNER_NAME as name, IP_MGMT_TBL.OWNER_DIV as owner_div, IP_MG
MT_TBL.REQUEST_TIME as request_time, ARP_TBL.PORT as port FROM IP_MGMT_TBL left join ARP_TBL on IP_MGMT_TBL.IP = ARP_TBL.ip WHERE ARP_TBL.ip=101.1.47.254;
err:Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.47.1; SELECT ARP_TBL.DEVICE_IP as dev
ice_ip, IP_MGMT_TBL.IP as ip, IP_MGMT_TBL.' at line 1
rows:undefined
```

This is what console log said. Also it's a part of full log though.
I think SQL queries seem to be fine but it doesn't work at queries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address needs to be quoted is the basic solution to the syntax error. Use a query of the form to eliminate the need for multiple queries:

```
... WHERE ARP_TBL.ip IN ('ip address1', 'ip address 2', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM ARP_TBL.ip
WHERE device_ip IN ('ip 1', 'ip 2',...)